# XAML WPF Data Templates

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have this XAML code:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication6.ApplicationView"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication6"
    Title="Simple MVVM Example" Height="350" Width="525">

<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:ApplicationViewModel}">
        <local:HomeView />
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:ProductViewModel}">
        <local:ProductsView />
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>

<DockPanel>
    <Border DockPanel.Dock="Left" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="0,0,1,0">
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding PageViewModels}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Button Content="{Binding Name}"
                            Command="{Binding DataContext.ChangePageCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}"
                            CommandParameter="{Binding }"
                            Margin="2,5"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </Border>

    <ContentControl Content="{Binding CurrentPageViewModel}" />
</DockPanel>
</Window>
```

The part in Window.Resources is giving an error: `Can't put a Window in a Style.` Both of the views throw the error, HomeView and ProductsView. I have some questions:

- Why do I get that error?
- What exactly does the code do?
- How can I fix the error?

Comment: Your code above is tying the viewmodel to the view.  Can you provide more detailed code for us to help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing that `HomeView` and `ProductsView` are of type `Window`, which is the error you are getting. Instead, they need to be a `UserControl` or similar type.

Comment: I got the code from a tutorial I was following when I change them to UserControl I get "Title was not found in type UserControl and Title is not  recognized or accessible

Comment: Because the property Title does not exist on UserControl type. Daniel is right: you cannot host a Window inside another Window on WPF.